# php-cgi got SIGKILL on burst.net VPS?

Tags: vps

I got an VPS at burst.net, very cheap one, but this doesn't matter.

The strange behavior of it is, the php-cgi process, which started using lighthttpd's spawn-cgi, dies every a few minutes. however, other processes are fine and great, even include a java process, and I'm sure there is no "out of memory" issue, so it's not killed by OOM killer.

I used strace to trace the process, and found out it was killed by SIGKILL, hence no single log was left on the disk, just dies suddenly.

Is there anyway I can find out what process/thing sent the SIGKILL to the poor php process?

Filed a ticket with the vendor, but they said they won't care.

```
strace -p 7176
Process 7176 attached - interrupt to quit
wait4(-1, <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

Comment: What kind of virtualization is used for your VM?

Comment: @mircea-vutcovici openvz it is

Comment: I've the same problem. It seems burst.net is killing cron daemon regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I recompiled the php using php-fpm, that seems to be much better and steady.
anyway, openvz is not as good. but you pay that little, what to expect?

Comment: Don't settle for OpenVZ crap; even at the low end you can find decent Xen and KVM hosts.

Comment: Make sure to accept this as your answer, so it's clear what solved your issue.  (When you can in a couple days).

Answer (score 0):

A singnal can be send only be a process run as the same user as the destination or as root. You can use systemtap to find the culprit. See: [SystemTap SigMon](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/#process/sigmon.stp)

Comment: thanks..this is a cool however it seems I need some new kernel to get it to work. yum install systemstap will give me a new kernel and I doubt it will not work on the VPS -- using openvz. probably I should find something using Xen

Comment: (systemtap does not require a new kernel; people have used it fine under a xen domu.)

Answer (score -1):

After asking the burst.net support, they changed something on the server. Cron is running continuously now.

It seems like crond was killed by the host system.